# Where is "Defaults requiretty" in Kali Linux (or similar)?

Tags: sudo, kali-linux

I noticed `sudo` does not work if fds 0/1/2 are not bound to a terminal.

I read that one fix is to delete `requiretty`, but this line isn't in `/etc/sudoers`, neither in the included directory `@includedir /etc/sudoers.d`.

Comment: Please read the documentation supplied with your system, `man sudoers`

Answer (score 0):

On modern versions of `sudo` in distributions like Kali, `requiretty` might be one of the compiled-in defaults.

If you are already root, `sudo -V` (note: upper-case V) should tell you the build-time conqman qfiguration options used with `sudo`, and other configuration information. If you are running as a regular user that has permission to run commands (but not a shell) as root through `sudo`, you can get this information with `sudo sudo -V`.

If `sudo` seems to default to `requiretty` behavior for any reason, and there is no explicit `requiretty` setting to remove, then you can always add an explicit setting to disable it. Just add this line to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults !requiretty
```